# Proc sql UPDATE ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name

Tags: sas, sql-update

I'm stuck trying to update a column default value on a table. I succesfully created the empty column in the table, but then when I run the update command it gives me back this error:

```
 85         proc sql;
 86         update CAPM
 87         set r_f = 1,0300;
                        ____
                        22
                        76
 ERROR 22-322: Expecting un nome.  
 
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
 
 NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
```

the code I am running is:

proc sql;
update CAPM
set r_f = 1,0300;
quit;

I already tried to put the number between '', but SAS states that are looking for a numeric value

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the comma doing there?

If are using it to represent the decimal point then use a period, not a comma.  If you mean it as thousands (or ten thousands) separator then remove it.